# python sklearn ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

training the sklearn sgd classifier. Based on name and age which are arrays, a color is obtained. b
Error with .fit() for sgdclassifier. Error: 'setting an array element with a sequence.' mean? Does this mean sgd classifier in sklearn cannot have arrays of arrays as inputs?

However no error if name and age are not arrays (and just single elements).

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np`

a=np.array([0, 2, 5, 2])
b=np.array( [0, 5, 0, 2])
c=np.array([2,2,0,0])
d=np.array([5,2,5,0])


age_a=np.array([5, 10, 7, 6])
age_b=np.array([3, 7, 11,8])
age_c=np.array([15, 10, 17, 2])
age_d=np.array([2, 8, 12,7])

color_a=np.array([0,2,1,1])
color_b=np.array([1,12,0,1])
color_c=np.array([0,1,1,0])
color_d=np.array([1,0,0,1])

#data2={'name':[a,b,c,d],'age':[age_a, age_b, age_c, age_d],'color':   [color_a,color_b,color_c,color_d]}

data2={'name':[a,b,c,d],'age':[age_a, age_b, age_c, age_d],'color':[0,1,0,1]}
new2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)

print(new2)

x = new2.loc[:, new2.columns != 'color']
y = new2.loc[:, 'color']

x=np.array(x,dtype=object)
y=np.array(y)



x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)



from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

sgd_clf=SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
sgd_clf.predict(x_test)`
```

`
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'list'

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[117], line 25
     21 print(y_test)
     24 clf = SGDClassifier(loss="hinge", penalty="l2", max_iter=5)
     25 clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
     26 #SGDClassifier(max_iter=100)
     28 clf.predict([[2., 2.]])


ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: If sklearn cannot be used, any other ml package in python which can be used?

Comment: Why you are not flattening your list? `x_flattened = np.array([np.concatenate((row['name'], row['age'])) for _, row in x.iterrows()])`

Comment: So flattening would make it a 1D array? Getting an error:---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 x_flattened = np.array([np.concatenate((row['name'], row['age'])) for _, row in x.iterrows()])

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Comment: My application is absically building a model from time series data. this was a test run I made: time=[0,1,2,3,4], pressure=[23, 45, 12, 7], temp_E85=25, status=Pass; time=[0,1,2,3,4], pressure=[3, 65, 1, 7], temp_E85=0, status=Fail; time=[0,1,2,3,4], pressure=[23 5 1 7], temp_E85=0, status=Pass; many data sets like these; trying to predict status (0 for Fail, 1 for pass).

Comment: Let me put the whole answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten your array like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 2, 5, 2])
b = np.array([0, 5, 0, 2])
c = np.array([2, 2, 0, 0])
d = np.array([5, 2, 5, 0])

age_a = np.array([5, 10, 7, 6])
age_b = np.array([3, 7, 11, 8])
age_c = np.array([15, 10, 17, 2])
age_d = np.array([2, 8, 12, 7])

color_a = np.array([0, 2, 1, 1])
color_b = np.array([1, 12, 0, 1])
color_c = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])
color_d = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])

data2 = {'name': [a, b, c, d], 'age': [age_a, age_b, age_c, age_d], 'color': [0, 1, 0, 1]}
new2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)

print(new2)

x = new2.loc[:, new2.columns != 'color']
y = new2.loc[:, 'color']

x_flattened = np.array([np.concatenate((row['name'], row['age'])) for _, row in x.iterrows()])
y = np.array(y)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_flattened, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
sgd_clf.predict(x_test)
```

To make an output like this one, that seems correct:

```
           name              age  color
0  [0, 2, 5, 2]    [5, 10, 7, 6]      0
1  [0, 5, 0, 2]    [3, 7, 11, 8]      1
2  [2, 2, 0, 0]  [15, 10, 17, 2]      0
3  [5, 2, 5, 0]    [2, 8, 12, 7]      1
```

Comment: Question: will flattening be appropriate for such data as for first row for example, for name =0 age=5, name=2 age=10 ...... ? I am new to ml.  I previously worked with data where name and age would be elements for each row rather than arrays.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it is related to your data, if each feature has a different len, flattening them into a single row can lead to inconsistencies. One solution to fix this can be changing of your two arrays into separate features for each index, like `name_1, name_2, name_3, name_4, age_1, age_2, age_3, age_4`. I don't know other statistical solutions to this.